# Strip text after comma to the end of line

Tags: javascript, regex, string, text

I need to strip all text after comma to the end of line. For example, I have a text like this:

> one, two, three\n
>   orange, white, blue

and i need to get smthing like this:

> one\n
>     orange

Comment: That's great...what have you tried?

Comment: I am not good with regex, so this is one way to solve it and I don't think its a good way. `var a = "one, two, three\n orange, white, blue"; var p = [];
a.split("\n").forEach(function(item){
   p.push(item.split(",")[0]);
}); p.join("\n");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a very simple regex:

```
replace(/,.*/g, '')
```

```js
var s = "one, two, three\n orange, white, blue";
console.log(s.replace(/,.*/g, ''));
```

**Details**:

- `,` - match `,` then...
- `.*` - 0+ characters other than a newline
- `/g` - multiple times

And replaces with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
const string = "one, two, three\n orange, white, blue";
const commaArray = string.split(',');
const lineBreakArray = commaArray[2].split('\n');
const myString = commaArray[0] + "\n" + lineBreakArray[1]; // one\n orange
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You can put that as an answer